# SQL Query For finding no of child departments for each department

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

**I would like to write a query which will return Dept Name and respective count of its children departments.**

I am having following table structure:

```
Table Name# Department
Dept_ID(Pk) Dept_name parent_dept_id(references dept_id)
```

Dummy data would be

```
DEPT_ID            DEPT_NAME            PARENT_DEP_ID   
1              HEAD OFFICE               1
2              ADMINISTRATION            1
3              ARTS                      2
4              SCIENCE                   2
12             Agriculture               2
5              COMP. SCIENCE             4
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think dept_id 1 must have parent_dep_id as 0.

Comment: Have you considered any answer to your post?

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cccd/11)**

**Below is the Query which you can try**

```
select P.DEPT_ID,P.DEPT_NAME,count(C.DEPT_ID)
  from Department P
  Left join Department C
    on p.DEPT_ID = C.PARENT_DEP_ID
   and p.DEPT_ID <> C.DEPT_ID
 group by P.DEPT_ID,P.DEPT_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Roms, would you plz spare some time and explain me that how exactly it works or functions

Comment: You wanted the ID,Name and Count of depts which are child to a DEPT. To do so simply `Join` the same tables on `(1st table's Parent_Dept_Id) = (2nd Table's Dept_ID)`. But in this case Depts which don't have child are not listed. Hence intead of `Join` i used `Left Join`. Hope it will clear your doubt.

Comment: I did understand how you made them related but tough part for me is how count(c.DEPT_ID) is being used? If you have a step by step way or debug way that how these joins worked, it will be great help

Comment: If I uses `Count(*)` then it also counts `null` if present. But in your case you don't want that to happen. Hence I used `count(c.DEPT_ID)` so that if `C.DEPT_ID` is `null` then it won't get counted. Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
Select count(*) as count, P.* from Department P 
  LEFT JOIN Department C ON p.dept_id = C.parent_dep_id
  GROUP BY C.parent_dep_id
```

Comment: I think that will no do the stuff since there is a tree structure in the table

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select *,count(ChildDepart.PARENT_DEP_ID)    from Department as ParentDepart inner join
Department as ChildDepart in ParentDepart.DEPT_ID = ChildDepart.PARENT_DEP_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DEPT_ID,DEPT_NAME,coalesce(dt.child,0) CHILD 
from department d
left join
(
  select PARENT_DEP_ID,count(1) child 
  from department 
  where DEPT_ID <> PARENT_DEP_ID 
  group by 1
)dt
on d.DEPT_ID=dt.PARENT_DEP_ID;
```